# Adding Security To Chat Client

Tags: c#, sockets, security

So this is my basic chat program which allows user to add its own IP and receive an IP, plus custom ports to communicate.

In the windows forms design I have:

Textbox    ---   textLocalIp

Textbox    ---   textLocalPort

Textbox    ---   textFriendIp

Textbox    ---   textFriendPort

Textbox    ---   textMessage

Listbox    ---   listMessage

Button    ---   Start

Button    ---   Send

So this is a very basic client but what I want help with is making it secure/more secure because security right now is not good.

Maybe like a tunnel with different IP's so that you don't have to know the receivers IP, just a IP they provide which then sends it to them or whatever?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;



namespace Client
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Socket sck;
        EndPoint epLocal, epRemote;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            sck.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

            textLocalIp.Text = GetLocalIP();
            textFriendIp.Text = GetLocalIP();

        }

        private string GetLocalIP()
        {
            IPHostEntry host;
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());

            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    return ip.ToString();
                }
            }

            return "127.0.0.1";

        }


        private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
        {
            try
            {
                int size = sck.EndReceiveFrom(aResult, ref epRemote);
                if (size > 0)
                {
                    byte[] recievedData = new byte[1464];

                    recievedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;

                    ASCIIEncoding eEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                    string receivedMessage = eEncoding.GetString(recievedData);
                    listMessage.Items.Add("Sender: "+receivedMessage);

                }

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

            }
            catch (Exception exp)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
            }

        }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
                byte[] msg = new byte[1500];
                msg = enc.GetBytes(textMessage.Text);

                sck.Send(msg);

                listMessage.Items.Add("Local:" + textMessage.Text);
                textMessage.Clear();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());

            }
        }

        private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                epLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textLocalIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textLocalPort.Text));
                sck.Bind(epLocal);

                epRemote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(textFriendIp.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textFriendPort.Text));
                sck.Connect(epRemote);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1500];
                sck.BeginReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref epRemote, new AsyncCallback(MessageCallBack), buffer);

                start.Text = "Connected";
                start.Enabled = false;
                send.Enabled = true;
                textMessage.Focus();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is more difficult to implement socket communication security using channels. So I suggest you encrypt the IP and transmission content.

For IP encryption, you can set the Passwordchar attribute of the TextBox to *.

For transmission content, you can encrypt it with an encryption algorithm.

The following code implements the communication between a server and multiple clients, and you can perform encryption on this basis.

Server:

```
 namespace Server
{
class Program
{
    private static byte[] result = new byte[1024];
    private static int myProt = 8885; 
    static Socket serverSocket;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                   
        serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, myProt)); 
        serverSocket.Listen(10); //Set up to 10 queued connection requests
        Console.WriteLine("Start listening {0} successfully", serverSocket.LocalEndPoint.ToString());      
        Thread myThread = new Thread(ListenClientConnect);
        myThread.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Listen for Client connections
    /// </summary>
    private static void ListenClientConnect()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.Accept();
            clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Server Say Hello"));
            Thread receiveThread = new Thread(ReceiveMessage);
            receiveThread.Start(clientSocket);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// receive data
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="clientSocket"></param>
    private static void ReceiveMessage(object clientSocket)
    {
        Socket myClientSocket = (Socket)clientSocket;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                
                int receiveNumber = myClientSocket.Receive(result);
                Console.WriteLine("Receive client {0} message {1}", myClientSocket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString(), Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result, 0, receiveNumber));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                myClientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                myClientSocket.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Client:

```
namespace Client
{
class Program
{
    private static byte[] result = new byte[1024];
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            clientSocket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ip, 8885)); 
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully connected to the server");
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to connect to the server, please press Enter to exit!");
            return;
        }
        //Receive data through clientSocket
        int receiveLength = clientSocket.Receive(result);
        Console.WriteLine("Server：{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result, 0, receiveLength));
        //Send data through clientSocket
        for (int i = 0; i <3; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000); 
                string sendMessage = "client send Message Hellp" + DateTime.Now;
                clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendMessage));
                Console.WriteLine("Client：{0}" + sendMessage);
            }
            catch
            {
                clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                clientSocket.Close();
                break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("After sending, press Enter to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```